# Swipe a uiView in Swift like Tab View Controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller, uitabview

I want to swipe a uiView like we use in tab view controller in SwiftUI but while using storyboard, if we use tab view controller whole screen is been swiped but i have to swipe only half of the screen and perform some functions there. i am attaching screenshot of it for better understanding:

[image: screenshot of my simulator]

I want this type of response. With the button **Add New Group** I am adding a new group, and by swiping I want to see my secondary groups.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What didn't work?

Comment: You can use `UICollectionView` instead of `UIVIew`. It can swipe your `UIView` from left to right as well as right to left

Comment: use the pagecontrol

Comment: share the code or complete steps in which way you are adding swiping in your view

Comment: @dasdom i tried tab bar controller but it swipes the whole screen

Comment: @MuhammadNawaz i had updated my question. hope you can understand it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

```
 let viewsList : [UIViewController] = {
        
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       
        let vc1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController")
        let vc2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
        let vc3 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewController")
        
        return [vc1, vc2, vc3]
        
    }()
```

add codes in viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
        
        if let firstvc = viewsList.first {
            self.setViewControllers([firstvc], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
    }
```

detect next page or previous page.

```
        func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [AnyObject], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
      if completed {
        if previousIndex < currentIndex {   // forward
    
        }
        else if previousIndex > currentIndex {  // reverse
    
        }
      }
    }
```